# async lambda does not return before awaited method returns

Tags: .net, asynchronous, async-await

Im trying to start using the async methods in .net 4.5 and I thought I had it figured out, but now when Im trying to do it in a func but I cant get the following to work:

```
Action task = async () =>
    {

            await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
            Debug.WriteLine("Save completed");

    };

task();

Debug.WriteLine("Returned");
```

The output will be:
Save completed
Returned

I expected it to be in the opposite order.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Edit 1:

I've created a sample code to show what I want, and the wierd thing is that it works perfectly:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (BCFdbEntities db = new BCFdbEntities())
        {
            IssueComment ic = db.IssueComments.First();

            ic.Comment = DateTime.Now.ToString() ;

            Action a = async () =>
                {
                    await db.SaveChangesAsync();

                    Console.WriteLine("Save completed");

                };

            a();
            Console.WriteLine("Returned");

            Console.ReadLine();

        }



    }
}
```

However, I cant make the exact same code work in my live code. 
The code is part of an addon to a commercial tool, could they be blocking it somehow?

Comment: What do you mean by "I cant get the following to work"? It's not clear what you're trying to achieve, what you expected to happen, what actually happens, or what context you're in (console app, web app, winforms/wpf app).

Comment: Sorry John, I accidently posted it before I was finished with it while I was addin tags.

Comment: Okay, so what does `SaveChangesAsync` do? (Is this EF for example?) Can you post a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem?

Comment: Yes, its the async method of SaveChanges in Entity Framework 6. 
Ok, I'll try to isolate it and post.

Answer (score 0):

> I expected it to be in the opposite order.

You can't expect anything, sorry. This is a race condition.

If you want to wait for the code to complete, then you can't use `Action`. You really shouldn't be using `Action` with `async` lambdas anyway, because they create an `async void` method. And you should avoid `async void` (more details in my [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx)).

Instead, you need to use the `async` equivalent of `Action`, which is `Func<Task>` (I describe this more [on my blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/02/synchronous-and-asynchronous-delegate.html)). With `Func<Task>`, your calling code can now `await` the lambda's execution:

```
Func<Task> task = async () =>
{
  await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
  Debug.WriteLine("Save completed");
};

await task();
Debug.WriteLine("Returned");
```

Comment: Ok, hmm, I tried your solution but it had the same result. 
I removed the await statement because I dont want to await the task, I want to await the _db.SaveChangesAsync() method and dont block my main thread.

Answer (score 0):

I think I solved it. 
The save was so quick that the method was not awaited. 
I added Task.Delay(5000) to slow it down to see if that was the case and then it worked as expected. After this I measured the time of execution and it was a mere 12 ms, not really sure on how to measure async methods so I included more code than might have been necessary.

```
            Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
            sw.Start();

            Func<Task> task = async () =>
            {
               // await Task.Delay(5000);
                await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
                Debug.WriteLine("Save completed");
            };

            task();
            Debug.WriteLine("Returned");

            sw.Stop();
```

Anyway, I did not expect the compiler to have an idea of whether to await a method or not, but apperently it does.

Thanks to Stephen Cleary for the suggestion on Func instead of Action. I will make sure to use that in the future!